# Get all active user sessions webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, session, webapp2

I am extending the dispatch method as specified in Webapp2 Sessions documentation:
https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#SessionStore

```
def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    try:
        # Dispatch the request.
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
        # Save all sessions.
        self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
        return self.session_store.get_session()
```

I want to get all the active sessions of a particular user for some purpose. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `UserToken` model.

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import UserToken

def all_sessions_for_user(user, _limit=100):
    return UserToken.query(UserToken.user == str(user.key.id()).fetch(limit=_limit)
```

EDIT - OPTION 2

Then, I believe the only way is to define your own session_store backend, most likely using the datastore. There is a datastore backend that webapp2 provides (backend options are `securecookie`, `datastore`, and `memcache`), but it doesn't have a user field.

So you would need to subclass both `Session` and `DatastoreSessionFactory` to add it:

```
from webapp2_extras import auth
from webapp2_extras.appengine.sessions_ndb import Session, DatastoreSessionFactory

class MySession(Session):
    user_id = ndb.KeyProperty(User)

class MyDatastoreSessionFactory(DatastoreSessionFactory):
    session_model = MySession

    def save_session(self, response):
        """extract user_id from self.session.data and pass it to self.session_model constructor"""

        if self.session is None or not self.session.modified:
            return

        deserialized_session = auth.get_auth().store.deserialize_session(self.session.data)

        self.session_model(id=self.sid, data=dict(self.session), user_id=deserialized_session['user_id'])._put()

        self.session_store.save_secure_cookie(response, self.name, {'_sid': self.sid}, **self.session_args)
```

And then when you call `get_session()`, you just need to specify your new backend factory:

```
self.session_store.get_session(factory=MyDatastoreSessionFactory')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Alex. Yeah I tried that, but don't think tokens are associated with the active sessions directly. For instance, if I have two active sessions of a user, and I delete one token from the datastore, the session associated with that token will still be active. Would help a lot if I am able to get the sessions (that are apparently stored somewhere else)

Comment: Well the `UserToken` was the only out-of-the-box persistent data i noticed. I think you may need to whip something up, see my edit